# What does word "meta" mean?

Tags: metaprogramming, metadata, terminology, template-meta-programming

What does the word mean?

Is it the same concept as in the cases below?

1. Template meta-programming in C++
2. meta-data in database or file systems

Comment: [This Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta) is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: You might be interested in Jeff's latest blog post ("Meta Is Murder"): http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001282.html

Comment: Jeff's talking about meta in a social context (meta-discussions). I really doubt he'd have anything bad to say about technical things like metadata.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: The OP put a "3..." so I guess it fits here. Also, to understand meta, one first has to understand understanding meta ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a word definition, not programming.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> In epistemology, the prefix meta- is
>   used to mean about (its own category).
>   For example, metadata are **data about**
>   **data** (who has produced them, when,
>   what format the data are in and so
>   on).

*Reference: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta)*

Answer (score 2):

Meta is Greek and means beyond (the real, actual) stuff.

Interestingly Meta-Physics means "Beyond the Physics", and comes from a Greek philosopher who wrote some books. One was "Physica" (these natural sciences), the next one "Meta-Physica" (because it came after, or beyond the "Physica") (and it dealt with the super natural scienses, e.g. religion). .... Nice anectode from a philosophy lecture, that helped me to remember these basics :-)

KR, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Template meta-programs are programs that produce programs, So this is another example of meta meaning about its own category as Dreas suggested.